# Creating a map from nested lists

Tags: java, collections, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

Suppose there are 3 classes:

```
class Level1 {
    int idLevel1;
    List<Level2> level2list;    
}

class Level2 {
    int idLevel2;
    List<Level3> level3list;    
}   

class Level3 {  
    int idLevel3;
    String name;
}
```

Suppose there is a List of Level1 objects called initial state

```
List<Level1> initialList = new ArrayList<>();
```

I want to create a map from initialList where:

```
 - Key: is idLevel1
 - Value: is list of all idLevel3 , corresponding to idLevel1
```

I am able to achieve this using for loops, but I want to achieve this in a more elegant way using Java 8 features (streams and the functions).
I tried using Collectors.toMap() also tried grouping but I am unable to get the desired map.

Comment: a series of two `flatMap`, it seems.

Comment: Show us your attempt - aside of giving an answer, we can also *help* you based on your attempt :)

Comment: `Elegant` does not necessarily mean `best`.

Comment: Shouldn't the `level2List` in the `Level2` class definition really be `level3List`?

Comment: @WJS yes you are right,  it should be  `level3List`

Comment: @WJS what according to you is the best solution ? I want to leanr the best solution as well.

Comment: It depends on your requirement.  But it would not be appropriate for me to pick one.  Any solution which meets your requirement would be a good choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By corresponding to `idLevel1` I made the assumption that you wanted a list of all `idlevel3` that were in the `chain` for the a particular `idLevel1`

So there could be a list of `level3 ids` for some `level1 id` and a different list of `level3 ids` for a different `level1 id`.

Based on that, this is what I came up with.

```
        Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = initialList
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors
                        .toMap(lv1 -> lv1.idLevel1,
                                lv1 -> lv1.level2list
                                        .stream()
                        .flatMap(lv2 -> lv2.level3list
                                .stream())
                        .map(lv3 -> lv3.idLevel3)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: Is this not same as the [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59654338/1746118)?

Comment: @Naman.  No.  I interpreted the requirement differently and did not do any filtering by comparing level1ID to level3ID as it made no sense to me (I could be wrong but I figure the OP will let me know).

Comment: And that could have been [worth a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59654115/creating-a-map-from-nested-lists#comment105474045_59654338) rather than an answer. Since the type collected in the existing answer still logically remains same.

Answer (score 2):

Similar approach to others:

```java
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = initialList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Level1::getIdLevel1,
                lv1 -> lv1.getLevel2list().stream()
                        .flatMap(lv2 -> lv2.getLevel3list().stream().map(Level3::getIdLevel3))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

I added getters in yout classes and change one name from `List<Level3> level2list;` to `List<Level3> level3list;`:

```java
class Level1 {
    int idLevel1;
    List<Level2> level2list;

    public int getIdLevel1() {
        return idLevel1;
    }

    public List<Level2> getLevel2list() {
        return level2list;
    }
}

class Level2 {
    int idLevel2;
    List<Level3> level3list;

    public List<Level3> getLevel3list(){
        return level3list;
    }
}

class Level3 {
    int idLevel3;
    String name;

    public int getIdLevel3() {
        return idLevel3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this which is valid but I have no data to test it so pls test it and give me feedback :).

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> map = 
        initialList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(f -> f.idLevel1,
                f -> f.level2list.stream()
                .flatMap(f2 -> f2.level2list.stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toList()).stream()
                .filter(f3 -> f3.idLevel3 == f.idLevel1)
                .map(f3 -> f3.name).collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: your approach was almost right, I think filter is not needed. Thank you for trying to help me.